# Access a model variable from another controller page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

**Setting** which functions as a post. It has the **variables**: Title:string Description:text, Photo:image and Paragraph:text.

I have another controller which controls my Home, About, News and contact.
On my Home, I'm trying to access the **title** of the **setting** with the **id 3**. I can't figure it out. Do i need to define the controls for the settings in the page controller as well? How can I access it?.

Here is my code at the **Home**,

```
<% @setting.(id[3]) do |setting| %>
<h2><%= setting.title %></h2>
<% end %>
```

**Error: Undified local varible or method 'id' for #<#**

Would appreciate some help, or a push in the right direction. Thanks :)

Comment: In controller set the @setting by `@setting = Setting.find(3)`, and then in view put `<h2><%= @setting.title %></h2>` without all this `<% @setting.(id[3]) do |setting| %>`

Comment: Okey but if I want to display for example setting id 1 at one place at the page and setting id 3 at another place, how do I make all the settings avalible in the controller? is it enough with `@settings = Settings.all` and `@setting = Setting.find(params[id])`, I'll try it :)

Comment: You could get them by `@settings = Setting.find([1,3])` and then use each of them into view.

Comment: Okey, how do i then display them in the html ( guessing that I should not use the find([1]) cuz i've already dont that in the controller)

Comment: It depends on your app and what are you going to do. For example, you can iterate through them: `<% @settings.each do |setting| %>` and then `<h2><%= setting.title %></h2>` and `<% end %>` at the end.

Comment: I want to display different parts of a setting spread out over the page, so i need to access a specific setting id and it's for example title.

Comment: Got another problem now.. My setting photo upload simply stopped to work, just says missing image, dont know if it has something to do with callbacks in my setting controller. `def set_setting @Setting.find(params[:id]) end or my whitelist def setting_aparams params.require(:setting).permit(:title, :description, :paragraph, :photo)end` :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display single record then there is no need to have loop, so you can try this.

```
<% setting = Setting.find(3) %>
<h2><%= setting.title %></h2>
```

Comment: worked but did not work with `<% setting = Setting.find(3) do%> <h2><%= setting.title %></h2><% end %>` If I want to display the title of the 4th post somewhere on the page the setting id is already defined, is it not? :) Thanks

Comment: And now for only one page you will get a lot of SQL requests to DB. Not so clever :)

Comment: you can also do this to display more than one record at any place in a view.
in your controller write
    `@setting = Setting.all`

and in your view 
    `<% setting = @setting.find(3) %>
    <h2><%= setting.title %></h2>`